# type of relation in many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have many to many association between 2 models in my project, but want to specify type of association between them.

something like this: we have Teachers et Classrooms, each Teacher has many Classrooms and each Classroom has many Teachers, we can create a relation Teaching if we want use Trough.

for exemple a Teacher is Teaching mathematic to one Classroom and the same Teacher is Teaching physics to another Classroom, is there a way to do something like that in activerecord, and if there is many ways to do that, which is the best way to go with?

edit:
i tried this method and i don't know if it is the best practice:

```
Class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :classrooms, through: :teachings
  end

  Class Teaching < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :teachers
    belongs_to :classrooms
  end

  Class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :teachers, through: :teachings
  end
```

my idea is instead of using Teaching: i'll use ohter models (ex: Math, Physic..) wich inherit from Teaching Model
if can i add type on Teaching association (using STI on association table)? and how can i implement it? or i simply add an attribute to Teaching and set it manually instead of using STI? wich is the best way to do?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you could use another table called subjects. That would allow a report that would show which teacher (teacher_id) is in which classroom (classroom_id) teaching which subject.

Comment: i don't understand very well your advise